# Outlook macro running twice

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, microsoft-outlook-2010, macros, duplicate

I use a macro to send an auto response to texts that come to my outlook. This works but it sends the reply to our customers twice every time. Any advice how to stop this. The macro is:

```
Sub ReplytoMessage(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Set myReply = Item.Reply
If Item.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
myReply.HTMLBody = "Thank you for your message. We will deal with it shortly." & vbCrLf & myReply.HTMLBody
Else
 myReply.Body = "Thank you for your message. We will deal with it shortly." & vbCrLf & myReply.Body
End If
myReply.Send
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you triggering the macro?

Comment: Through a rule: When a message arrives with SMS in the subject and on this computer only. Run 'Project1.ThisOutlookSession.ReplytoMessage and stop processing more rules

Comment: Have you confirmed you don't have more than on copy of that rule?  Also, are they are getting two different emails sent that are identical (headers and all?), or are they just seeing the body multiple times, or ???

Comment: I only have 1 copy of the rule. The rule is for only if it is in the subject. I think the macro is just running twice

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this macro to find why this macro is being run twice.